# company computers with proxy but no gateway?

Tags: proxy, ip, gateway

Can I safely assume that client computers in my customers environment do have a configured gateway (whether static or DHCP)?

It looks obvious but I wonder if this scenario is realistic: In corporate networks that feature a proxy server to let users connect the Internet, does it happen that the DHCP setup includes no gateway for client computers, assuming that the proxy server is located in the local subnet hence computers don't need a gateway to access the Internet?

Answer (score 2):

If a company has every client and server on a single subnet, then yes.. clients could potentially be without a default gateway, if they are using a proxy.

Not all applications are proxy-aware, so I would call it a horrible, *horrible* setup.

But yes, it is possible.